# Change style class by changing scoped variable value

Tags: javascript, css, xpages

I have a button inside an xpages div and I am trying to compute the style class of that button based on a scoped variable.

Initially, the scoped variable's value is 'blue' and the background color of the button inside the div is blue as well.

When I click on a second button, I set the value of the scoped variable to 'green' and do a partial refresh of the div.

Now, I would expect the button to turn green, but the class is not being changed.

Here is the SSJS for computing the style class:

```
if(sessionScope.sTest == 'green'){
    return 'btn-success';
}
else{
    return 'btn-primary';
}
```

So, my question is, is a style class recalculated during a partial refresh or would I have to resort to either JQuery or Dojo in order to change the style class.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: An easier solution would be to use jQuery and to use the addClass() and removeClass() functions.

Comment: post the code that uses the return string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you disable the theme for the button it should work

```
<xp:button id="btn" disableTheme="true"></xp:button>
```

Comment: Hello Thomas, that worked! Wonder why you have to disable the theme though. Even though I am loading all the Bootstrap files by using a theme, I still have to tell the button, what class it is (btn-danger, btn-success etc) and would have thought I can change the class like that.

Comment: This problem is related to the JSF phases. Theme defines button class in concat mode, so it needs to be set before the page loaded. That's why, if you need to compute styleClass for buttons on bootstrap, you need to disable theme. You might also use Mark's solution here. http://linqed.eu/2014/08/28/xpages-gotcha-modeconcat-in-your-themes

Comment: Thank you Serdar for explaining it, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't compare Java Strings like that, use .equals("...") instead.

Comment: Hello Oliver, thanks for your response. Sorry for the question, but how would I use .equals in this case?

Comment: This does not apply to Javascript.

Comment: Pataar, Serverside Javascript is conveted to Java at runtime. It's not Clientside Javascript that's used here.

Comment: @OliverBusse: Wouldn't it be better to use === instead of .equals?