# Computed styleClass on an xp:button does not appear to work correctly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages

I am trying to compute the styleClass on a button to a BootStrap button format, but the compute. the button always displays as the btn-warning and does not shift between that and the btn-success. I have the identical code on the

```
<xp:button value="History" id="button1">
<xp:this.styleClass><![CDATA[#{javascript:var key:String = compositeData.linkKey;
if (viewScope.vsShowHistory == key){
    return "btn btn-warning btn-sm"
}else{
    return "btn btn-success btn-sm"
}}]]>
                                            </xp:this.styleClass>
<xp:span>
<xp:this.styleClass><![CDATA[#{javascript:var key:String = compositeData.linkKey;
if (viewScope.vsShowHistory == key){
    return "glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign";
}else{
    return "glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign";
}}]]></xp:this.styleClass>
</xp:span>

<xp:eventHandler
    event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial"
    refreshId="panelHistory">
<xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var key:String = compositeData.linkKey;
if (viewScope.vsShowHistory == key){
    viewScope.remove("vsShowHistory");
    sessionScope.remove("ssShowHistory");
}else{
    viewScope.vsShowHistory = key;
    sessionScope.ssShowHistory = key;
}}]]></xp:this.action>
</xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had the same issue with computed button styleclass in Notes/Domino 8.5.3 Changing to div or span helps. It looked like Viewscope variables were always null when calling them from button styleclass. Exactly same code works by just changing button tag to div..

Comment: I'll have to try that. I just added two buttons with exact opposite visble formulas and that works. Probably not the best solution but it works. Will try something like this when I have some time to kill.

Comment: I ran into this very issue today.  Yeah this is messed up!  I ended up switching the buttons to <xp:link> and that seems to have corrected it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the issue is in the Bootstrap themes due to the mode used to add style classes to every button control. You can read more about it here in a blog post by Mark Leusink, who adds a suggested workaround as well: http://linqed.eu/2014/08/28/xpages-gotcha-modeconcat-in-your-themes/

Also there's a simpler workaround posted here: [Change style class by changing scoped variable value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27694776/change-style-class-by-changing-scoped-variable-value/27695510#27695510)

This may be something we need to fix in the ExtLib.

Answer (score 0):

Bill,
It looks like you're missing some of the question/info?  It seemed to stop.

I don't think this is reliable :

```
viewScope.vsShowHistory == key
```

I'm not exactly sure what data key is but since it is a string you probably want something more like : 
viewScope.vsShowHistory.equals(key)

I think they way you're doing it is comparing OBJECTS and not the VALUES.

Comment: The strange thing is the comparison works fine for the <xp:span> to select styleClass for the  glyph-icon but does not select the correct styleClass for the <xp:button> using identical code. I'm guessing that the button styleClass might only be computed on load or something like that.

Comment: I'm just toggling the color and icon on the button depending of if the viewScope.vsShowHistory == key so I just created two buttons and flip the visible property based on (viewScope.vsShowHistory) ? true : false in one and the reverse in the other. It works but.....